# swiping through Uiimageview pffile array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview, swipe

Working code to download array and print image:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Cats")
    query.orderByDescending("objectId")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({( objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if(error == nil){

            //let imageObjects = objects as! [PFFile]


                //if (rightSwipe.direction == .Right) {
                    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(objects!.count)))
                    println(randomNumber)


                for object : PFObject in objects as! [PFObject] {

                    let thumbNail = object["image"] as! PFFile
                    println(thumbNail)

                thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)

                            self.shoesImageView.image = image

                    }

                })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end
            //}

            }//for - end

        }
        else{
            println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
        }

    })
```

Parse class photo:

[image]

photo of running app:

[image]

photo of storyboard:

[image]

What my goal is, is to swipe through images on each uiimage view. If you look at the output it is printing the array, I just don't know how to get it to swipe through the photos. Last, if there is a way to implement a form of randomization for the swipe that would be great. I've been tinkering with this for quite some time now and no luck.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to build an app similar to a photo gallery, then I recommend that you use a scroll view and let the user scroll with paging enabled.

Comment: Welp my goal was a similar style to more like tinder or something with that idea. I dont want to make a tinder clone, just want swipeable images. am I going about this the wrong way then?